# Can I use a variable as the name of a field in a form?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I am trying to set a validation rule for a form to see if fields are populated.

I figure using an array of field names within the current form and a loop will solve this without too much coding. Trying to use the array value in the loop is my struggle.

```vb
Dim avFields As Variant
Dim vItem As Variant
      
avFields = Array("inSurvey#", "txtProjectName", "cboPracticeType", "cboProjectType", "cboClient", "txtLaunchDt", "txtEndDt", "cboCRM", "cboPM1", "cboLC1", "cboAN1", "cboCO1", "cboSC1", "cboPRI")
      
For Each vItem In avFields
    Debug.Print vItem
    If IsNull(Me.[vbitem]) Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter a Project Name", vbOKOnly
        Me.vItem.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next
```

The hang up is in `Me.vItem.SetFocus`.

Comment: @sSidChamring are "fields" form controls? or are they table columns?

Comment: Yes you can but you have to use the `Controls` collection. `If IsNull(Me.Controls(vbitem)) Then ...`

Comment: @Kostas: I think the 'controls' feature does not direct me to the field.  I changed my code to include your suggestion and it bypasses the if statement when the fields are actually blank. Thanks though!

Comment: @ Doug Coats: Fields are the names of [Text Boxes] within a form. example Last Name text box which I'll name [txtLastName] is being verified as populated before continuing to the next step in the submittal process of the form.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate of [How can a reference fields on an Access form using a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20477408/9439330)

You can't use a variable after a dot, as it is has to be a member of the object (here: the form).  You have to use the Controls-Collection, which is a member of the form and pass the variable to the Item-Property `Me.Controls.Item(vItem)`, that returns the reference to the control.

```
If IsNull(Me.Controls(vItem)) Then   ' short for Me.Controls.Item(vItem).Value
  MsgBox "Please Enter a Project Name", vbOKOnly
  Me(vItem).SetFocus ' short for Me.Controls(vItem).SetFocus
  Exit Sub
End If
```

If you need to refer a member by a var that has no collection you can use the [CallByName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/callbyname-function) function like this:

```
Set myControl = CallByName(Me, vItem, vbGet)
```

Update:

> I changed my code to include your suggestion and it bypasses the if statement when the fields are actually blank

brings me to `IsNull(Me.myTextBox)`is not reliable in any cases. If you want to use the Fields input before the AfterUpdate event of the control, the value is not set and you have to use `Me.myTextBox.Text`.

Another trap: `Me.myTextBox(.Value)`can be an empty string `""` (different to NULL). This has to be catched by:

```
If Len(Me.Controls(vItem) & vbNullString) = 0 Then ' if control.value is NULL the result string is an empty string (vbNullString is the const for "") as NULL & "" = "". Len() is used instead of Me.Controls(vItem) & vbNullString = vbNullString, because it is faster.
```

Comment: this didn't help me other than I did use it to structure my if statement.

Comment: You don't want to refer to `Me.inSurvey#, Me.txtProjectName, .. `? `Me.[vItem]` is not a control? `IsNull(Me.[vbitem]) `is not a typo? Use [Option Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/option-explicit-statement)!

Comment: @SidCharming: I think your If-Statement is wrong, see my updated answer.

Comment: I changed my "If" statement as indicated in your update above... I got an error that I have a suspician is due to the name having a special character.  Error is: "Run-time error 2465: Microsoft Access can't find the field 'inSurvey#' referred to in your expression"  Am I on the right track of thinking?

Comment: Rename(suggestet, allowed chars `A-Z,a-z,0-9`,_  and avoid keywords like Name, etc.) or use square-brackets `[inSurvey#]`.

Comment: Thank you!  It's been a while since I've done this much detail in Access so I seem to have lost the limitations (I also thought Access removed the old limitations)... :)

Comment: That's no Ms-Access limitation (as you can use s-brackets), but a general programming convention. Special-chars sometimes want to be "special" ;). Problem solved?

Comment: Thank you ComputerVersteher!